# JQuery parse.JSON ignore undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I have an API that returns a large JSON response via AJAX.  I `parse.JSON` and loop through with jQuery `$.each` to append results to a DOM element.  The script needs to account for all potential key/values since sometimes they are not in JSON (e.g. address direction) in the address object.

This results in an `undefined` written to the address element in the page.

(e.g. -> 123 undefined Maple Street undefined )

I can detect undefined values to prevent `undefined` being written into the page like this:

```
$.each(json.address_list, function(i, val) {

  if (typeof this.address.street_direction !== 'undefined') { 
    var street_direction = this.address.street_direction 
  } else { 
    var street_direction = '' 
  };

  $('#address_line').append('<p>'+street_number+' '+street_direction+' '+street_name+' '+street_suffix+' '+unit_number+'</p>;

});
```

This seems like a lot of code to have to check all the values (street_suffix, unit number, etc) to prevent `undefined` written to the DOM element?

Is there a quick method or shortened syntax to ignore `undefined` variables? I've searched everywhere, and can't find a simple lightweight solution.  I'd think it's very common when parsing JSON?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'Hello ' + (window.nameOfSomeoneUndefind || '') + ', nice to meet you';
```

Comment: Thanks, this syntax works!  Is there any other JS or jQuery directive to ignore undefined variables in the function?  Othwerise, I need to do this for every var.